# How to identify if a method of underlying type held by a shared_ptr can be invoked with one or no parameters at compile time

Tags: c++, invocable

Using C++ 17. I have the following:

```
template <typename T>
using ptr_t = std::shared_ptr<const T>;

class some_type;

class A { some_type foo() const; }
class B { some_type foo() const; }
class C { some_type foo(int) const; }

std::variant<ptr_t<A>, ptr_t<B>, ptr_t<C>>;
```

A variant holds shared_ptr(s) to different types. All expected to have function ***foo()*** that may be void or take a parameter. I will then have a visitor that would correctly dispatch foo, something like this (conceptually):

```
struct visitor
{
  template <typename T>
  ptr_t<some_type> operator()(const T& config) const
  {
    if constexpr (// determine if foo() of the underlying type of a shared_ptr can be called with int param)
        return config->foo(15);
    else
        return config->foo();
  }
```

is there a way to say this? I tried various ways but can't come with something that compiles. Template parameter, T, is ptr_t<A|B|C>.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable

Comment: Intsead of using `if constexpr` I would suggest to make a `callable_wrapper<T>` that would wrapp `T::operator()()`  into `operator()(int)`. Then initialize specialize the variant. That way you will be able to use `std::visit` like it was intended

Comment: Sorry, not sure I follow. But The idea is not to have any specialization for all types in a variant as it will then require changing the visitor code every time a new type is added.

Answer (score 1):

1. `std::is_invocable_v<Callable, Args...>` is the way to go. Unfortunatelly, it will not compile just like that with `if constexpr`. It will either fail because "there is no `operator()()` overload", or there is no overload for operator taking `Args...`.
2. I suggest you add a wrapper class for a callable and use it with a specialized alias template of `std::variant` instead of writing your own visitor. It will allow you to use `std::visit` seamlessly.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <variant>

template <typename Callable>
class wrapped_callable
{
    Callable c;
public:
    wrapped_callable(Callable c)
        : c(c)
    {}

    template <typename ... Args>
    constexpr decltype(auto) operator()(Args &&... args) const
    {
        return _invoke(std::is_invocable<Callable, Args...>{}, c, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

private:
    using _invocable = std::true_type;
    using _non_invocable = std::false_type;

    template <typename T, typename ... Args>
    constexpr static decltype(auto) _invoke(_invocable, const T& t, Args &&... args)
    {
        return t(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    template <typename T, typename ... Args>
    constexpr static decltype(auto) _invoke(_non_invocable, const T& t, Args ... args)
    {
        return t();
    }
};

template <typename ... T>
using variant_callable = std::variant<wrapped_callable<T>...>;

struct int_callable
{
    int operator()(int i) const
    {
        return i;
    }
};

struct non_callable
{
    int operator()() const
    {
        return 42;
    }
};

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using variant_t = variant_callable<int_callable, non_callable>;

    // 23 is ignored, 42 is printed
    std::visit([](const auto &callable){
        std::cout << callable(23) << '\n';
    }, variant_t{non_callable()});

    // 23 is passed along and printed
    std::visit([](const auto &callable){
        std::cout << callable(23) << '\n';
    }, variant_t{int_callable()});
}
```

```
Program returned: 0
42
23
```

https://godbolt.org/z/e6GzvW6n6

> But The idea is not to have any specialization for all types in a variant as it will then require changing the visitor code every time a new type is added.
> That is what template alias of `std::variant<wrapped_callable<T>...>` for. You just add append a new type to the list, that's it.

Take notice, that it does not depend on `if constexpr`. So if you manage to provide your own `variant` and `is_invocable_v`, it will work for C++14. For C++11 possibly, but some modifications regarding `constexpr` functions might be needed.

---

Of course you can implement your `visitor` in the same manner if you want to use `std::shared_ptr` istead of a callable.
But I don't see any reason to use:

- visitor + smart pointer. Just use a smart pointer - it will give you runtime polymorphism in a "classic" way (via virtual inheritence)
- why `std::shared_ptr`? Do you really need to share the ownership? Just stick with `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: I see, thanks Sergey for detailed explanation. The variant and use of shared_ptr is built into framework's implementation. And it does share the ownership.

Comment: @M.K. I see. Then you just implement your `visitor` in the same manner (just change the class name), except that `_invoke` needs to call `ptr->foo()`